# Request for mod help: please stop the conflict with this user

Tags: support

This is about [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/64752) and the OP who--for reasons beyond me--refuses to use the "accept answer" button and only wants to leave comments saying it's the correct one (and to also complain about being bullied?).

I've asked the user to stop because they're effectively spamming me, even if it's infrequently.  That hasn't worked.

Please either stop deleting the user's comments or otherwise stop them from commenting?  Otherwise I think I'll just delete the answer.  I have limited capacity to devote to being exhausted by things these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you - I had left them an informal message, but have now suspended them with a stricter warning about their behaviour.